# Akkusativ and Dativ pronomen

Tags: grammatical-case

> Ihn möchte ich ein Geschenk geben.

Is this correct? Like when we have stress in *Ihn* as direct object can we write it in such way.
Mostly I have seen

> Ich möchte ihm ein Geschenk geben.

But what if stress is in person we are giving to then can it be

> Ich möchte ihn ein Geschenk geben.

Comment: When discussing German, thinking in direct/indirect object categories will only confuse, never help you. You have to know which case goes with objects of the verb. Many verbs first take an accusative object, then a dative object, but nearly as many verbs take a dative object only. And there's two dozen verbs which take a genitive object, half a dozen which take **two** accusative objects and another half a dozen which take a "nominative object" in some situations. And these three latter groups are common verbs.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can place the dative pronoun at the beginning of your sentence. However, it has to be "Ihm" (dative) instead of "Ihn" (accusative).

So you can either say

> Ich möchte **ihm** ein Geschenk geben.

or

> **Ihm** möchte ich ein Geschenk geben.

if you want to stress who you want to put the emphasis on the recipient of the present.

---

> Ich möchte **ihn** ein Geschenk geben.

and

> **Ihn** möchte ich ein Geschenk geben.

are always wrong because the recipient has to be in the dative case.

Who are you giving it to? -> dative case -> ihm

What are you giving? -> accusative case -> ein Geschenk